# Check if input is int and also if in range of 2 numbers - Python

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I'm trying to build a Tic Tac Toe program,

I want to check if the input is between 1-3 and also if the input is int only by using while, for and if statements.

the second test going well, but if the input is for example 4
I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

**

> 

```
    X = input("Pick row between 1-3: ")
    while X not in range (1,4):
        if X.isdigit()==False:
            print ("Wrong input, try again!")
            X = input("Pick row between 1-3: ")
        else:
            X=int(X) 
    Y = input("Pick colum between 1-3: ")
    while Y not in range (1,4):
        if Y.isdigit()==False:
            print ("Wrong input, try again!")
            Y = input("Pick colum between 1-3: ")
        else:
            Y=int(Y)
```

**

Comment: Your bug: `X=int(X) ` and after that you call isdigit

Comment: from what I can see what you want is if Y is between 1 and 3.
so you should do `Y = int(Y)` and then check
  `1 <= Y and Y<=3`

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep things simple. I think this is what you want to solve:

```
X = input("Pick row between 1-3: ")
if int(X)<1 or int(X)>3:
    print ("Wrong input, try again!")
    X = input("Pick row between 1-3: ")
Y = input("Pick colum between 1-3: ")
if int(Y)<1 or int(Y)>3:
    print ("Wrong input, try again!")
    Y = input("Pick row between 1-3: ")
```